# Do I have to use the same passport to go to Japan everytime?

Tags: passports, japan, dual-nationality

I have two passports. One is Hong Kong (HKSAR)passport.  One is British Citizen passport (GBR).
For both passports, they are visa exempted to enter to Japan.
My question is last month I used the British passport to go to Japan. I am going to Japan in next two weeks and I want to use the Hong Kong passport. Is it okay?

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the advantage?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat doesn't have to have an advantage - perhaps the British one is expired or lost.

Answer (score 18):

Totally fine.  As long as you enter and exit the destination country on the same passport, it's acceptable.

There are some rules for citizens returning to their country, eg American citizens are obliged to enter the US on their American passport, but generally, as long as you arrive/exit using the same passport (And it doesn't have to be the same as last time - you might have changed citizenship in that time!), you'll be fine.

Comment: In general, is this still ok if using the second passport would mean that you're getting around restrictions about entering _too often_ in a certain period on the first one?

Comment: @TimMalone that is a very good question,  and not something I've considered.  Might be worth a new question on this site!

Comment: @TimMalone Japan has no such restrictions. And in any case, they can see that you are the same person from your fingerprints.

Comment: @fkraiem No, they actually can't.  They can *confirm* you're the same person by comparing fingerprints, but they'd need to suspect that for some other reason first.  (Identical names & birthdates, for example.)

Comment: @TimMalone Japan doesn't actually have published restrictions about how often you can enter, it's up to the discretion of the immigration officer (and, most likely, unpublished guidance).

Comment: @jpatokal So they actually can, then...

Comment: @TimMalone - in general, it is not ok to try to get around restrictions no matter how you think they work.  It is possible that they wouldn't track the visits accurately if they were looking at entries of the passport rather than the person (if you were not talking about Japan, but somewhere which has such restrictions) - but it is also possible that they would track the person, or notice the same name and birthdate then check, and then... there would be trouble.  Better to keep track of restrictions and not violate them, even if you might have multiple passports for such shenanigans.